# Zooming Animation in Google Maps

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I am learning about `Google Maps API` on `Android` and I have just learned how to do this.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    // Add a marker in Uman and move the camera
    LatLng uman = new LatLng(48.754683, 30.216339 );
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(uman).title("Home Town"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(uman, 10));
}
```

But instead of the map loading directly into the marker, I want it to load fully zoomed out, and zoom in into the marker in an animation...

Really hope that makes sense...

Comment: hey.. any update on this?

Answer (score 7):

Do mMap.animateCamera(...) instead of mMap.moveCamera(..)

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    // Add a marker in Uman and move the camera
    LatLng uman = new LatLng(48.754683, 30.216339 );
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(uman).title("Home Town"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(uman, 10.0F));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make the zoom animated

Answer (score 4):

Try this ....

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    // Add a marker in Uman and move the camera
    LatLng uman = new LatLng(48.754683, 30.216339 );
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(uman).title("Home Town"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(uman, 10));
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                       
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(uman, 16));
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for animation replace moveCamera to animateCamera

**java**

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
```

**kotlin:**

```
 val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f)
 map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)
```